# stack more LSTM hidden layers dynamically by input values

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, hidden

My script like this:

```
lstm_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(50, return_sequences=True),
                                          input_shape=x_train.shape[-2:]),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation='relu'),
            tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(50, return_sequences=True)),
            tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(50)),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation='relu'),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(output),
        ])
```

How can I add more LSTM hidden layers of:

```
tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(50, return_sequences=True))
```

I meant dynamic by input values, for example, 2 will double it, and 3 will make triple

I tried:

```
dense_layers = [tf.keras.layers.LSTM(50, return_sequences=True) for _ in range(2)]
```

Then inside the model, I called it:

```
tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(dense_layers),
```

But it showed me the following error:

```
ValueError: Please initialize `Bidirectional` layer with a `tf.keras.layers.Layer` instance. Received: [<keras.layers.recurrent_v2.LSTM object at 0x000001DD0E924490>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is your goal with the hidden layers

Comment: @GoldenLion I want to know if more hidden layers can improve the accuracy of the prediction, and how much it can improve, I meant I don't know how much I need, that is why I need to test them by adding one layer more at each test, in addition, I need to have a low number of layers as I can with the highly accurate results. I have a limitation in the RAM also.

Comment: hidden layers capture feature patterns in the data.   I think large neural layers can improve recognition slightly.  deep learning networks use very big data set to capture small percentage gains in performance.  I think a new organic based neural network structure will improve performance. the mathematical activation functions of signal process are not accurate enough.

Comment: @GoldenLion, what do you suggest? add more layers or keep it as is and increase the number of neurons?

Comment: I don't know.  When you look at image res net it used several hidden layers to acheive its accuracy.   think of each hidden layer as a filter.  the more filters you apply the more differentation in the image becomes possible.   I often wonder if an classifier trained on recognizing an orange can differentate from an orange with a fruit label.  see hopfield networks for partial image recognition.

Comment: @GoldenLion Thanks a lot for the clarification. but is there a way for doing that?

Comment: do you want me to show you how to setup a cnn image recognition network?